# Duplicate devices in device manager

Tags: windows-10, drivers, device-manager

When choosing the option "show hidden devices" in device manager, I can see many duplicate hidden devices:

[image]

Is that normal? Can I delete the disconnected ones safely?

Also, I have noticed that in IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers I have two identical AMD SATA Controller devices, is that normal? Could that cause a very long boot time (I am trying to solve that issue right now, posted in my previous question)? Can I uninstall one of them?

[image]

Motherboard: Gigabyte AB350M-D3H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows manages each USB device individually. One "device" from the perspective of Windows is one USB device connected to a specific USB port. Thus if you have connected the same USB device two times (using of course different USB ports) Windows manages each device individually.

However this also means that if you have devices you frequently switch the used USB port (or even use a hub) for each USB port you have used the device one device entry is created.

In your case it looks like you have multiple devices like mouse, keyboard (= HID device) or USB flash/hard discs used on different USB ports. And the greyed out entries belong to those device that were connected once.

If the entry is from an USB device you can safely delete those entries, but you don't have to. You don't gain much from deleting them.

Regarding the SATA controller(s) you should leave everything as it is. If Windows detects multiple controllers and all of them are active/working (not greyed out and no yellow exclamation mark) then everything is fine and there will be a reason for that.

Comment: What about the second GPU? And the SATA Controller?

Comment: @IvanGorin Just leave them even when greyed out. They don't hurt.

Comment: Ok, do you know what a solution to the problem in my previous question could be? (the two AMD SATA Controllers booting for 600+ seconds)