# Can I remove hidden devices from Device Manager on Windows

Tags: windows

I have been using the same Windows install since XP, just upgrading as new versions came along.  I am on Windows 10 now.

In Device Manager, there are many hidden devices.  At a glance, over 100 hidden devices.  I think most of the hardware ones are from previous motherboards.

**Is it safe to uninstall/delete the drivers?**

To test, I had a Realtek device from the previous motherboard, I deleted it and rescanned the devices.  It has not come back.

[This Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1616434/duplicate-devices-in-device-manager) is not a duplicate because it is talking about USB devices.  I am not concerned about USB devices.

**EDIT -**

1. What I am trying to achieve is to remove a decade (or more) of mess as I have upgraded my motherboards and other hardware devices.  I am capable of figuring out which ones are definitely non-existent devices.
2. The other annoyance is that `Driver Easy` keeps finding updates for them.  I would rather not waste my time updating these phantom devices.

Comment: “I think most of the hardware ones are from previous motherboards.” - This isn’t how hidden devices work. What are you trying to achieve by uninstalling devices that are hidden?

Comment: Non-present devices are a _subset_ of all hidden devices. They have “faded” icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft article
[Viewing Hidden Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/viewing-hidden-devices)
says this:

> Device Manager lists the devices that are installed in the computer.
> By default, certain devices aren't shown in the list. These hidden
> devices include:
>
> - Devices that have the device node (devnode) status bit DN_NO_SHOW_IN_DM set.
> - Devices that are part of a device setup class that is marked as a NoDisplayClass (for example, printers and non-PnP drivers)
> - Devices that were physically removed from the computer but whose registry entries weren't deleted (also known as non-present devices or
>   phantom devices).

Of the three causes for devices being hidden, two relate to devices
whose drivers (or Windows) have marked them intentionally as hidden
from the users, not because they are not being used.

The third cause relates to devices that were physically removed,
but removing the drivers will mean that they will not be recognized
when/if the devices are physically attached again.

These are good reasons for not deleting drivers of hidden devices,
as this might cause Windows to malfunction.

You do not get any benefits from removing the drivers
except saving a very small amount of disk space.
Balanced against the possibility of harming the functioning
of Windows, their removal is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Device Manager in a properly running computer works fine.

Do NOT delete Hidden Devices.  Don't. There is not any need to do this and nothing significant will be accomplished. It is possible to create problems removing drivers you are not familiar with, and in the worst case, require reinstalling the operating system.

They are used to run the computer and peripherals properly.

Leave this kind of stuff alone as Windows knows what to do and how to manage.

If a driver shows an error (red or yellow X) then repair the driver or hardware.